# Is there a way to create a dynamic paint object/brush that absorbs wave motion rather than reflect it?

Tags: dynamic-paint

Within dynamic paint, let's say there was a wave incident on an object (a wall created by a mesh cube, for example), but rather than reflect the wave, you would like it to absorb (completely damp) that energy as the animation continues. Is there a brush (or other) option for this object that would allow for this? This wall may have holes, etc..., so I can't simply open the borders and leave this wall as the edge of the field. Thank you!